# In Haskell how to pass a constructor as a parameter and match over it

Tags: haskell, constructor

I have this code

```
data Container = Box Int | Bag Int


inBox :: [Container] -> Int
inBox [] = 0
inBox (x:ls) | (Box i) <- x = i + inBox ls
             | otherwise = inBox ls


inBag :: [Container] -> Int
inBag [] = 0
inBag (x:ls) | (Bag i) <- x = i + inBag ls
             | otherwise = inBag ls
```

Clearly `InBox` and `InBag` have the same structure. I would like to make a function that encompass both of them. What I don't know how to get is to pass the constructor (either `Box` or `Bag`) as a parameter.

Ideally, the general function woul look something like this:

```
inSome :: Constructor -> [Container] -> Int
inSome con [] = 0
inSome con (x:ls) | (con i) <- x = i + inSome con ls
                  | otherwise = inSome con ls
```

Obviously that doesn't work because constructor is not a defined type here. How can I do it?

One idea is to pass it as a function like so:

```
inSome :: (Int -> Container) -> [Container] -> Int
inSome _ [] = 0
inSome con (x:ls) | (con i) <- x = i + inSome ls
                  | otherwise = inSome ls
```

But then I get the error:

> Parse error in pattern: con

Because it cannot match on functions like that.

The reason I want to do this is because I have a complicated data type that includes binary operations (e.g. +, #, ::, etc...) I have several functions that are almost identical for these constructors. I would hate to write all of them and modify them all together. There must me a way to do it in a function. Maybe someone can suggest another approach in the comments?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: define `unContainer :: (Int->a)->(Int->a)->Container->a`, then `inBox (x:ls) = unContainer (+(inBox ls)) (const (inBox ls)) x`, and `inBag` is the same but swap `unContainer` arguments. If you wanted, you could generalize some more, so really inBox and inBag would differ by `flip`, but in this particular case I don't see why you'd want to do that.

Comment: Edited to explain why I want that, hope it helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can avoid using pattern matching here entirely.

```
data Container = Box Int | Bag Int

unBox, unBag :: Container -> Maybe Int

unBox (Box i) = Just i
unBox _       = Nothing

unBag (Bag i) = Just i
unBag _       = Nothing
```

The type of these functions captures the need to get the contained `Int` out while switching on the structure of the `Container`. This can then be used to build the functions you desire.

```
inSome :: (Container -> Maybe Int) -> [Container] -> Int
inSome get []     = 0
inSome get (x:ls) = fromMaybe 0 (get x) + inSome ls

inBag = inSome unBag
inBox = inSome unBox
```

---

As leftroundabout noted, the pattern of "get or fail" is (massively) generalized in the concept of the `Lens`, or, in this case, the `Prism`. In general, [`Prism`s can form a weak kind of first-class pattern](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v%3aoutside), but their use here would be certain overkill.

Comment: Beat me to it - this is exactly what you should do, unless you have some particularly pressing need to be able to pass patterns around.

Comment: Seems like a perfect workaround. But to make sure, there is no direct way of passing constructors as parameters without using Lens? Is there a fundamental reason for limitation?

Comment: You can pass a constructor---they're just functions after-all---you just can't parameterize a pattern match, they must be concrete. That said, those restrictions are to be lifted in GHC 7.10.

Answer (score 5):

You might like [first-class-patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/first-class-patterns), a package that lets you pass and munge patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You want a [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lenses)ׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅׅ

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to count only one type depending on an argument, you could use a plain enum type to do the job. All that is needed essentially is a label to differentiate the type of operations you want. Passing the constructor or a wrapper such `make_bag`, `make_box` does not do better, and they can't be used in the pattern match as is.

```
data ConType = ON_BAG | ON_BOX
inCon :: ConType -> [Container] -> Int
inCon _ [] = 0 
inCon t (x:ls) | ON_BAG <-t,(Bag i) <- x = i + (inCon t ls)
               | ON_BOX <-t,(Box i) <- x = i + (inCon t ls)
               | otherwise = inCon t ls
```

---

If you want to sum the numbers in the boxes and bags separately, I think you can do:

```
inCont :: [Container] -> (Int,Int)
inCont [] = (0,0)
inCont (x:ls) | (Bag i) <- x = addP (i,0) (inCont ls)
              | (Box i) <- x = addP (0,i) (inCont ls)
              | otherwise = inCont ls
```

To count them together is even easier:

```
inCont2 :: [Container] -> Int
inCont2 [] = 0
inCont2 (x:ls) | (Bag i) <- x = i + (inCont2 ls)
              | (Box i) <- x = i + (inCont2 ls)
              | otherwise = inCont2 ls
```

Comment: What I need is a function that generalizes both functions. Your solution is useful, but not what I'm looking for.

I want the function to count only one (i.e. the boxes xor the bags) but which one depends on an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting up your container into two datatypes:

```
data Sort = Bag | Box deriving (Eq, Show)
data Container = Container Sort Int deriving (Show)
```

Defining `Sort` allows us to talk about sorts of containers without actually referring to any particular container.  This lets us do more interesting things:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

--  Pull out the value regardless of sort
getVal :: Container -> Int
getVal (Container _ val) = val

--  If the sort passes a predicate, we get just the value
unwrapIf :: (Sort -> Bool) -> Container -> Maybe Int
unwrapIf p (Container b v) = if p b then Just v else Nothing

--  If a given sort matches the container, we get just the value
unwrap :: Sort -> Container -> Maybe Int
unwrap p = unwrapIf (p ==)

--  Unwrap with a default value if one was not found
unwrapDefault :: Int -> Sort -> Container -> Int
unwrapDefault def p = fromMaybe def . unwrap p

--  Unwrap with a default value of 0
unwrapValue :: Sort -> Container -> Int
unwrapValue = unwrapDefault 0

--  Unwrap Bag values, else 0
unbag :: Container -> Int
unbag = unwrapValue Bag

--  Unwrap Box values, else 0
unbox :: Container -> Int
unbox = unwrapValue Box

--  sum up the values in a list of containers
sumAll :: [Container] -> Int
sumAll = sum . map getVal

--  sum up the values in a list of one sort of container
sumContainer :: Sort -> [Container] -> Int
sumContainer s = sum . map (unwrapValue s)

--  sum up the bag values in a list of containers
sumBag :: [Container] -> Int
sumBag = sumContainer Bag

--  sum up the box values in a list of containers
sumBox :: [Container] -> Int
sumBox = sumContainer Box
```

Here `sumContainer` is equivalent to your ideal `inSome` function, and `sumBag`/`sumBox` are `inBag`/`inBox` respectively.

If you want to take it a step further, try generalising `Container` to allow any value:

```
data Container a = Container Sort a deriving (Show)
```

Hope this helps!